# Fill DIV container with HTML table specified in other PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

How do I need to change `loadPopupManual()` in order to fill DIV `#popup_manual` with what I have in `content.php`? In particular, I need to insert the table specified in `content.php` into `#popup_manual`. This table must have all the functionality (some buttons) defined by scripts in `content.php`.

**test.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadPopupManual();
});

function loadPopupManual() {    // to load the PopupManual DIV
    $('#popup_manual').fadeIn("slow");  
}

<div id="popup_manual">
    // I need to fill this DIV with what I have in 'content.php'
</div>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

    $query="SELECT * FROM aircrafts;";
    $result=execute_query($query);

?>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         $(document).ready(function(){
             //...
         }
</script>

<table>
<tr>
//... some content is inserted here from DB ($result)
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `$.get`

```
$.get('content.php', function(data) {
    $('#popup_manual').html(data);
});
```

so it will become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadPopupManual();
});

function loadPopupManual() {    // to load the PopupManual DIV
    $('#popup_manual').fadeIn("slow"); 
    $.get('content.php', function(data) {
        $('#popup_manual').html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Will it save all the scripts defined in content.php? Or will it only display the table filled with DB data?